# Where does PIP Store / Save Python 3 Modules / Packages on Windows 8?

Tags: python, pip

I have looked everywhere and can't find where the packages are installed.

Further, are the packages from [pip](/questions/tagged/pip), modules, libraries or just packages in [python](/questions/tagged/python) terminology?

Comment: Really, you should always use a virtualenv, and then libraries will be stored locally in lib/site-packages inside that virtualenv.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html)

> Python usually stores its library (and thereby your site-packages folder) in the installation directory. So, if you had installed Python to C:\Python\, the default library would reside in C:\Python\Lib\ and third-party modules should be stored in C:\Python\Lib\site-packages.

Answer (score 61):

Use this command to list *global packages* with their locations:

```sh
pip list -v

# output example (windows 10):
# Package                   Version   Location                                                         Installer
# ------------------------- --------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- ---------
# adal                      0.4.5     c:\users\test\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages      pip
# aiocache                  0.10.0    c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages                      pip
```

When using [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) the *local packages* is located in project folder:

```sh
<project folder>\venv\Lib\site-packages
```

Comment: In addition to this answer that has worked for me, here's a possibly more readable/indelible form of the command using **--long-option**: `pip list --verbose` ([reference](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/?highlight=--verbose#cmdoption-v)). For more *options*, one could refer the documentation of [`pip list`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_list/#pip-list).

Answer (score 33):

for python 3.X default location C:\Users\username \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages

Comment: For me some where at C:\Users\<username>\AppData\ **Roaming** \Python\Python37\site-packages\

Comment: For me it is in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9, is it common? I don't know what I did, I think I usually choose the defalt.

Answer (score 2):

**It depends on how/where your python was installed.**

For example:

- if you are using `Conda` for your python, you will *most likely* find your packages in the default location of:

```xml
c:\users\<username>\miniconda3\lib\site-packages
```

- Whereas, if you installed `Python3.8` as a *stand-alone*, you will find it under:

```xml
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\
```

where if you install a simply pip package (that did not use any specific locations), and just having some scripts, it will end up in:

```xml
C:\Python38\Scripts\
```

<sub>Noting that if the script depend on libraries, it will probably not work, as they will not be found from this location, if installed on Windows, and not taking this into account.</sub>

- Or if you used `Cygwin`, they'll end up in one of:

```sh
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages      
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

---

Again, you best bet is to check with:

```sh
pip -V
pip list -v
```

There is also a pip package called [`pip-date`](https://pypi.org/project/pip-date/) that contain a utility called `pipbyday` that will show you the location of each package and the installation time.