# (Dumb noob) Will changing directory in cmd.exe prior to installing a third party module, cause that module to be stored in that directory?

Tags: python, file, cmd, directory, command

I want to install python, and then some additional modules, to my computer (windows).

I've been told that the best way to install python and packages is to make a folder in your drive somewhere BEFORE installing anything, (ex. 'Python') then pointing all your downloads (using cd in the command line) to this folder so that everything is in once place, and you don't have to go on a wild goose chase to make sure everything you want access to is in your PATH when you go to import modules etc.

Do I have the right idea?

I have had trouble importing modules in the past because they were not in the Path.

Will changing the directory in the command line before typing:

```
pip install somemodule
```

cause that module to be saved to where I just changed the directory to?

Comment: No, that is not how `pip` works at all. exactly where it stores it is based on where your python interpreter is located, in `site-packages`. see, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522743/where-does-pip-store-save-python-3-modules-packages-on-windows-8

Comment: To address your concerns specifically, the Python installer for Windows will create its own Python folder and ask if you want to add it to the path. Just tell it yes and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip always installs the libraries in a fixed directory, usually in the user folder. You can check this by the command `pip show <installed-package-name>`

So you can use any package you already installed to get the pip directory. The location might vary based on your python version and env name.

Example: `c:\users\<user>\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages`